# How to overload an asset for one of many targets in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcasset

Simply:

Within XCode I have 7 targets, one for every client. For every target I have a different `.xcasssets` file. Also I have **one** `.xcassets` that is attached to every target, as there are icons the same for every client.

Now there is a point:

One icon is the same for all of them, but different for the last one. Simply I have tried to overload an icon, and I just added it **also** to the last target, but Xcode displays that one from the *common* `.xcassets`. Is there a way to resolve this without separating the same icons between every target?

Comment: You can't move that one icon outside to target specific assets? It would be just 2 additional asset catalogs

Comment: Yes, I can, but now I am looking solution for overloading;)

Comment: There is no overloading for files in Xcode